# Migration File name starting at weird number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Recently, after I deleted some manually created migrations that were named 99999999xxx_createwhatever, each migration I generate now start with 99999999999999xxx_etc

Any idea how to fix this so that they are generated like 2011xxxxxx again?

Comment: Try creating a dummy/basic/empty migration file manually, with todays date and time and then create a migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your data in database, use `mysqldump` to backup first.

Then reset your migration to version 0 `rake db:migrate VERSION=0`

Make sure there isn't any 99999999x migration file, then run `rake db:migrate`

Finally, restore your database.